# Index outside bounds in event handler

Tags: vb.net, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm having some trouble displaying the shipping price to the `lblshipping.text`

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain
    Private intMin() As Integer = {1, 11, 51, 101}
    Private intMax() As Integer = {10, 50, 100}
    Private dblShip() As Double = {15, 10, 5, 0}

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtordered_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtOrdered.KeyPress
        ' allows the text box to accept numbers and the Backspace key

        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtordered_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtOrdered.TextChanged
        lblShipping.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        Dim intOrdered As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(txtOrdered.Text, intOrdered)

        For intIndex As Integer = 0 To 3
            If intOrdered <= 2 Then
                If intOrdered >= intMin(intIndex) And intOrdered <= intMax(intIndex) Then
                    lblShipping.Text = dblShip(intIndex).ToString("C2")
                End If
            End If
            If intIndex = 3 Then
                If intOrdered >= intMin(intIndex) Then
                    lblShipping.Text = dblShip(intIndex).ToString("C2")
                End If
            End If
        Next intIndex
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Make your code **minimal** and remove the unnecessary cruft. Post the **real** code (yours uses `Option Strict On` which is good, but it wouldn’t compile!) and be **specific** about the error – where does it occur? Your code makes it very hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete this statements

```
Private Sub txtordered_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtOrdered.TextChanged
    lblShipping.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

and try to change your for next statements

```
For intIndex As Integer = 0 To 3
        If intOrdered <= 2 Then
            If intOrdered >= intMin(intIndex) And intOrdered <= intMax(intIndex) Then
                lblShipping.Text = dblShip(intIndex).ToString("C2")
            End If
       elseIf intIndex = 3 Then
            If intOrdered >= intMin(intIndex) Then
                lblShipping.Text = dblShip(intIndex).ToString("C2")
            End If
        End If
    Next intIndex
```

Comment: Why these changes? THey don’t seem to have anything to do with OP’s problem.

Comment: Delete statements > cause i think that lbl shipping wont be having value if got that statements.. About for loop, just for minimal the code