# Visual Basic - use parallel arrays for displaying shipping charges based on input entered by user

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I really stink at using arrays.  I have this working with a 2 dimensional array but cannot figure out how to get it working with parallel one dimensional arrays.  The Display Shipping button's Click even should display a shipping charge based on the number of items entered by the user.  I am storing the minimum order amounts and shipping charges in parallel arrays.  I cannot get the calculations to work correctly.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Public Class frmMain
    'declare parallel arrays
    Private strNums() As String = {"1", "11", "51", "101"}
    Private intShipping() As Integer = {15, 10, 5, 0}

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtordered_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtOrdered.KeyPress
        ' allows the text box to accept numbers and the Backspace key

        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtordered_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtOrdered.TextChanged
        lblShipping.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        'displays the shipping price based on orders
        Dim strSearchForNum As Integer
        Dim intSub As Integer

        Integer.TryParse(txtOrdered.Text, strSearchForNum)

        'search the array for the orders greater than zero
        'if less than zero show error message
        'otherwise display shipping charge

        Do Until intSub >= strNums.Length OrElse
          strSearchForNum >= CDbl(strNums(intSub))
            intSub += 1
        Loop
        If strSearchForNum = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number greater than 0", "Number of Orders")
        Else
            lblShipping.Text = intShipping(intSub).ToString("C2")

        End If

        txtOrdered.Focus()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: a) `TryParse` returns a bool, you should check if the textbox *can* parse b) the Do loop could be `For each n as integer in...`   or even `Array.IndexOf()` to find the value

Comment: This looks strangely a lot like this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846197/index-outside-bounds-in-event-handler